# SceneKit creates visual artifacts on Collada (DAE) morphs

Tags: xcode, scenekit, maya, collada

I have a simple sphere model created in Maya and exported as .DAE (OpenCollada).

There is one blendshape (morph) target.
[image: Sphere with 0 morph applied.]

You can see it under Geometry Morphers on the right sidebar.
Name of morpher (blend shape target) is pCubeShape2.
Currently it's set to 0.

Now if I set morpher value to 1. As on the screenshot below. You will notice slight "harder" edges effect appearing on the exact location of UV seam.
[image: Sphere with morph applied with value of 1.]

If I change morph value all the way to 10 This effect becomes very noticeable.
[image: Sphere with morph applied with value of 10.]

Notice how on one side of edge faces become a bit brighter (left part of seam)
and darker on the other side of the seam.

Does anybody know what is this and how to eliminate these nasty artifacts?

As on real models it looks unacceptable and none of export options from Maya helped to get rid of these seams.

[image]

Thank you.